# docker-compose exec: \"webserver\": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

When I run my docker-compose.yml file using `docker-compose up`, it outputs:

```
Removing airflow_webserver_1
Starting airflow_postgres_1 ... done
Recreating bfec6e557af5_airflow_webserver_1 ... error

ERROR: for bfec6e557af5_airflow_webserver_1  Cannot start service webserver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"webserver\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

ERROR: for webserver  Cannot start service webserver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"webserver\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Before running `docker-compose up` I ran `docker build .` using a Dockerfile that was successful. So far i've only tried quitting, restarting Docker, and using `docker system prune -a` to remove docker images, containers, volumes, and networks.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/local/airflow/
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

Here's the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        # image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=n
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
            - ./plugins/:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3

        build:
            context .
            args:
                PYTHON_DEPS: "boto3==1.12.41, notebook==6.0.3, numpy==1.18.1, pandas==0.25.3, psycopg2==2.8.4"
                AIRFLOW_DEPS: "aws, postgres"
```

Here's the requirement.txt file:

```
boto3==1.12.41
notebook==6.0.3
numpy==1.18.1
pandas==0.25.3
psycopg2==2.8.4
```

Comment: What's the `CMD` the Dockerfile is supposed to run?  The `docker-compose.yml` has an override `command: webserver`; where does that command get installed?

Comment: Is there a command `webserver` that's supposed to work inside the container? You need to define what should get executed when the container starts, by using `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` in Dockerfile or in `command` inside docker-compose.

Comment: Your Dockerfile seems to miss a `FROM` line.

Comment: @DavidMaze The command I want to run is the `pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`. I'm very new to docker and I'm unsure where the `command: webserver` gets installed.

Comment: @Wander3r I defined `CMD bash script/entrypoint.sh` using the entrypoint.sh from https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/script/entrypoint.sh and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions:

1. Why you have a `healthcheck` and `command` params in you `docker-compose.yml` file? Are you sure you need them there and not in `Dockerfile` file?
2. You building image with arguments `PYTHON_DEPS` and `AIRFLOW_DEPS`, where you are using them? Remember you are using `FROM python:3` system where only python installed.
3. `image: puckel/docker-airflow:latest` -- are you maintainer of this image?
4. Can you explain WHAT you want to do in `Dockerfile`, becouse you just copying your filed to only python installed image.

As I understand you exstend some functionality of `puckel/docker-airflow` by adding your code, then you need:

1. Use from `FROM puckel/docker-airflow:latest` in your `Dockerfile`
2. Set you tag on to build `docker build -t my-airflow .`
3. Change `image` value on `docker-compose.yml` to `image: my-airflow`
4. Run it.
   Then everything make sense.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.

1. I'm very new to docker, I was experimenting with the docker-compose.yml file from this repo: https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/blob/master/docker-compose-LocalExecutor.yml that happen to have the health check in it.
2. I used the arguments because the Dockerfile wasn't importing the packages from requirement.txt 
3. Nope, I changed it
4. Specify the config for the image such as python packages, entry point, and default command for container.